# Creating SQL Assembly error Method parent has circular class type parameter constraints

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-clr

I'm trying to add an assembly to SQL server 2012 but I'm getting the following errors. I've tested the dll and it works fine from C# so don't think it's a code issue.  Any suggestions?

```
Msg 6218, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'HMDACalculateULICheckDigit' failed because assembly 'HMDACalculateULICheckDigit' failed verification. Check if the referenced assemblies are up-to-date and trusted (for external_access or unsafe) to execute in the database. CLR Verifier error messages if any will follow this message
[ : CalculateULICheckDigitCLR::.ctor][mdToken=0x6000002][offset 0x00000000] Method parent has circular class type parameter constraints.
[ : CalculateULICheckDigitCLR::CalculateULICheckDigitHMDA][mdToken=0x6000001][offset 0x00000000] Method parent has circular class type parameter constraints.
```

The C# itself is pretty simple.

```
public class CalculateULICheckDigitCLR
{
public static int CalculateULICheckDigitHMDA(string val)
{
    int result;

    result =  (int)(BigInteger.Parse(val) % 97);
    return result;
}
}
```

Example of value I'm passing in 548322619182814292318016211461767828260500

Answer (score 2):

The issue probably has something to do with the [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.1) class. It is found in **System.Numerics** which is not in the list of [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/supported-net-framework-libraries). Which means that you probably loaded that manually as `UNSAFE` (or have not loaded it yet?). Which then means that your assembly, **HMDACalculateULICheckDigit**, needs to be marked as `UNSAFE`.

This assessment is further supported by the fact that you got a "failed verification" error message, since verification is a process that happens at `CREATE ASSEMBLY` time and checks for obvious indicators of requiring `UNSAFE`.

Comment: Ok, trying to find an alternative way, but if I can't I'll give this a try.  I tried using double instead as it was the only other data type big enough to hold the number I have to use, but that doesn't appear to be giving me the correct value.

Comment: Well, how big of a number? Can you post that into the question? `double` (in .NET) / `FLOAT` (in T-SQL) is an imprecise type and does not provide accuracy across all digits.

Comment: Added to question.

Comment: that's a 42-digit number. `Decimal` can only hold 28 digits in .NET and up to 38 in T-SQL. The .NET `double` / T-SQL `FLOAT` doesn't even account for that many digits. I think it is 16 or 17 actual digits those can store. So if you need accuracy in the calculation you will likely need `BigInteger`.